# select list items from the union with another list

Tags: c#, linq, silverlight

Programming in silverlight / c#.

I have 2 lists set up right now:

```
list<string> quote_id = new List<int>();
List<getdata> merge = new List<getdata>();

public class getdata    
{
    public string month { get; set; }
    public string event_action_cd { get; set; }
    public string quote_id { get; set; }
}
```

What i really want is to return a list with all the quote_id that appear in both lists.
(in sql terms: select * from quote_id, merge where quote_id.quote_id = merge.quote_id)

How can I do that?  I know Linq can probably help me but I am new to Linq operators.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `Select * From merge where quote_id in ("","")...`

```
var query = merge.Where(r=> quote_id.Contains(r.quote_id));
```

If you want a list then you can append `ToList` to the query.

Also I believe your `quote_id` is defined as:

```
List<string> quote_id = new List<string>();
```

Comment: sorry yes its new list<string>, made a mistake when editing the copy/paste.
the merge function - which reference is it using?  I tried system.linq but its not there

Comment: @user2799598, it is `using System.Linq`;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.union%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) extension method.

```
var query = quote_id.Union(merge.Select(data=>data.quote_id));
```

This will return a IEnumerable is which the `merge` collection contains the items from the `quote_id` collection.

I would not recommend using the Contains method as this will do a sequential search for each item in the other collection. This will have a huge performance impact.